# Writing to a Type 5 NFC tag from iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc, core-nfc

I have a Type 5 tag with an NXP iCode Slix chipbase. The exact datasheet for the tag is [here](https://www.murata.com/%7E/media/webrenewal/products/rfid/rfid/uhf/uhf-smd/media-datasheets/hf%20magicstrap%20lxms33hcng_134%20datasheet%20160121%20v1_1.ashx). How do I use my iOS device to write an NDEF formatted message onto it? Does it matter that my phone is on iOS 13?

When I tried to do this, none of the NFC tag writing apps would allow me to write to the tag. If anyone has any info to shed on this, I'd be interested in hearing. The goal is to write a URL to these tags that can be read through the background tag scanning function on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the NXP Icode Slix chips are not formatted for NDEF Storage by default.
There is no Capability Container as defined by the [NFC Type 2 Spec](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf)
There is no Empty TLV Block as as defined by the [NFC Type 2 Spec](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf)

All blocks are delivered with `00h` values from the factory.

There is a procedure to initialise them as [NFC Type 2 Spec](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf) cards.
See Section 6.5 of the correct [Application Note](https://www.dangerousthings.com/wp-content/uploads/I-CODE_SLI-NFC-AN11042.pdf)

This should be possible https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfciso15693tag Apple NFC methods to write the correct data to Blocks 0 and 1 on iOS 13 and above.

I would not expect most NFC writing Apps to bother with formatting cards as NDEF capable as this was not possible pre iOS 13 and most are pre formatted from the factory, though I would expect that [NXP's TagWriter App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nfc-tagwriter-by-nxp/id1246143221) to have this capability (It does on the Android version).

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. I've heard the NXP TagWriter App was limited on iOS, but I wasn't sure in what ways. I'll try to reformat using one of my old android phones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Murata chip but with NXP's [ICODE SLIX](https://seritag.com/nfc-tags/29mm-white-icode-slix2) chips, then they need to have NDEF data already on them. If you encode them with an Android phone (and don't lock them) then you should be able to encode them with an iPhone.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to dig up my old galaxy and reformat using that. Do you have a recommendation on applications to do this with using an android?